# Problems with updating database with iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I will try describe my problem as best as I can. I have created a sqlite database using the console on the mac. I've added the file to my project, by right clicking and hitting "add files to (projectname)" and it adds the database. I am able to read the database, however when I try and update the database, although my debugging has confirmed the statements (update statements) succeed, the data in the database is not updating. I am gathering this is because the pointer to the database file is pointing to the .sql file in my documents (which is where the original file that I added is located), however I thought by adding the file to the project, a copy of that file would go within the project folder.

My question is how can I add a .sql file to my project where it is not referenced from the desktop, and be able to update the information that is located within the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the file is not the one on your desktop, the file be bundled in the .app bundle.

The database is located in the app bundle which is readonly, you will need to move the database to the document directory on first startup.

place something like this in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *sqlFile =[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdb.sql"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlFile]) {
   NSString *bundleSql = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourdb" ofType:@"sql"];

   NSError *error = nil;
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundleSql toPath:sqlFile error:&error];

   if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Could not copy json file: %@", error);
   }
}
```

Comment: so basically copy and paste the .sql into the applications directory?

Comment: No, you neeed to do it with code, in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` check if the file exists in the document directory. If no copy it there.

Comment: yep copied over perfectly. Now I just have to find the file path on the device :D

Comment: NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *sqlFile =[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdb.sql"];

Answer (score 0):

Get your SQL file's directory path on your bundle by :

```
NSString *sqlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourSQLFileName" ofType:@"sql"];
```

Next copy the sql file to your sandbox directory using this command :

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *sandboxDirectoryPath = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *newSQLFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/YourSQLFileName.sql", sandboxDirectoryPath];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sqlFilePath toPath:newSQLFilePath error:error]
```